# How to add a long integer to existing program

Tags: java, int, long-integer

The code works. But, I need to include long integers. How can I do that? I've tried a million things. I'm not good at this either so it takes me 5 times longer to get a simple code. Please help.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Exercise2_6M
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // Create a Scanner
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        // Enter amount
        System.out.print("Enter an integer:");
        int integer = input.nextInt();
        // Calculations
        int rinteger = Math. abs (integer);
        int sum = 0;
        int i=0;
        while(rinteger / Math.pow(10,i) > 0)
        {
            sum+=getDigit(rinteger,i);
            i++;
        }
        // Display results
        System.out.println("Sum all digits in " + integer + " is " + sum);
    }
    public static int getDigit(int num, int power)
    {
        return (num % (int)Math.pow(10,power+1)) / (int)Math.pow(10,power);
    }
}
```

Comment: Any reason why you are using an "int" instead of "long" or "bigInteger?"

Comment: Just replace int with long and Integer with Long. i.e. `int integer = input.nextInt();` -> `long val = input.nextLong()`

Comment: I tried using Long, but I woulg get an error. I didnt do I right it seems. Do i have to change the i's to something?

Comment: How large are the numbers you are dealing with?  Is it possible that the number is even too large for a long?  Also, if you are using a primitive data type it's "long," and if you want to use an object it's "Long" (notice the capital L).  If you are using an object, you will have to create it as you would a class object.

Comment: thank you so much. I had to change what you told me slightly. it was actually long Long = input.nextLong (). YOu told me what to do correctly, but I think you accidently added val. Can't believe this whole time I was so close.

Comment: @user972077 It wasn't an accident, it was just a variable name. I cannot urge you strongly enough *not* to use `long Long = input.nextLong();` anywhere ever--it's for your own safety.

Answer (score 2):

Read the input value as a string and then use the BigInteger class to perform calculations with very large values​​.

Answer (score 0):

A recursive solution can be much leaner:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Exercise2_6M
 {
    public static void main (String [] args)
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.print ("Enter an long:");
        long lng = input.nextLong ();
        int sum = getDigitSum (lng);
        System.out.println ("Sum all digits in " + lng + " is " + sum);
    }

    public static int getDigitSum (long num)
    {
        if (num < 10L) return (int) num;
        else return ((int)(num % 10)) + getDigitSum (num/10L);
    }
}
```